# Iterative sinus function in scheme

Tags: function, math, scheme, racket

So, I recently started learning scheme, through DrRacket, and I have to write an iterative function for *sinus*. This is what I got so far:

```
(define (calc-sin x n)
  (define (iter ctr res fac xpow sign)
    (if (>= ctr n)
        res
        (let* ((i (- (* 2 ctr) 1))
              (newfac (* fac i (+ i 1)))
              (newxpow (expt x i))
              (newsign (- sign)))
         (iter (+ ctr 1)
               (+ res (/ (* newsign newxpow) newfac))
               newfac
               newxpow
               newsign))))
  (iter 1 1 1 1 -1))
```

The code runs, but every time I try and insert a value, I get wrong answer, and as soon as I try to edit my answer, I get a `bad syntax` error.
If someone could take a look, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you would iterate

```
newterm = -term *x*x / (i*(i+1))
newres = res+newterm
```

which avoids overflow problems in the factorial and is computationally more efficient.

---

But the more immediate problem is that your used factorial is `(2*ctr)!` while you need `(2*ctr-1)!`.

You could reorganize your code so that `fac` is `(2*ctr-1)!` and the result of `newfac` is `(2*ctr+1)!`, i.e., `fac*(i+1)*(i+2)`.

---

Next problem: You start with `res=1` where it should either be `res=0, ctr=1` or `res=x, ctr=2`. In the latter case you would also have no problem with initializing `fac=1` and computing `newfac = fac*(i-1)*i` so that `newfac=(2*ctr-1)!`.